# How to choose between parametric and non-parametric regressions?

Tags: linear-model, nonparametric, nonparametric-regression

I am new to nonparametric regressions.
What tests should one perform to choose a non-parametric regression model over a parametric one(Or vice versa)?
Let's assume in our analysis we have a continuous dependent variable Y and regressors - X1 which is categorical and X2, which is continuous.
We then perform a a simple linear regression for the parametric model and then run the nonparametric regression.

What should be tested if both regressors look significant and with reasonable coefficients?

EDIT: The nonparametric model here in particular is "Local Constant Kernel Regression"

Comment: There are many forms of nonparametric regression and even more forms of semiparametric models.  Describe which methods you are referring to.  State the over-arching goals of your analysis also.

Comment: Well, one reason to not use OLS parametric  regression is due to violations of normality from the residuals. What do your residuals look like?

Comment: Normal for both models.

Comment: You should also mention how you will be using the results of your regression. If you are using the model for inference, note that many nonparametric regression methods, in lieu of a model with parameters, require the entire training dataset to make predictions. If the training set is very large, this could be prohibitive. For example, I perform logistic regression to datasets that are many to hundreds of gigabytes in size. A nonparametric model to be used by colleagues is not helpful if they must copy all this data.

Comment: The dataset is quite small - 500 observations. I just curious how we can compare these very different models so I can select the "better" one - to somehow back up my preference. I couldn't find any R package that would calculate AIC or BIC for nonparametric models. I suppose cross validation could bet the choice then.

Comment: There a are methods of computing the effective degrees of freedom for some types of non-parametric regression, such as smoothing splines. As @FrankHarrell asks, you should be more specific about the different models you are considering.

Comment: it's really important whether by "nonparametric" you mean something like additive models/splines or whether you are referring to classical (rank-based) nonparametric approaches such as Spearman correlations/Kendall's tau. (Or quantile regression or ...)

Comment: I am talking here in particular about Local Constant Kernel Regression

Comment: Jeffrey S. Racine in Nonparametric Econometrics: A Primer apparently names R-squared as one of the options for model evaluation.

Comment: @user3810441 If you're asking a specific question about a specific dataset to answer a specific problem, then [be specific](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl). I gave you a general answer because you weren't specific.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question of which model to use for a given problem is an area of statistics unto itself, which is called *model selection*. Methods for this include AIC, cross-validation, and Bayesian model selection. Most introductory statistics textbooks will include material on model selection.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's question. In my experience at least, model selection assumes we are assessing competing *parametric* models.

Comment: @BenBolker There's no reason you can't do model selection between parametric and nonparametric models. Some methods may be limited to parametric models (such as AIC), but that's just a limitation of the specific method. My own preference is for cross-validation, which is totally neutral to the parametric form (or lack thereof) of the model.

Comment: Hmm.  OK (especially since OP says they're doing kernel regression) -- I was thinking about methods like Spearman correlations, which provide p-values but not predictions.  Nevertheless ... this isn't very specific advice ...

Comment: @BenBolker To my understanding, Spearman correlation isn't a regression model, or even a model at all. It's just a measure of association.

Comment: Fair enough.  Again, OP was pretty vague about what they were doing (although the fact that they say "reasonable coefficients" implies a real regression model).